# Is the Charmed 2018 reboot happening in an alternate reality?

Tags: charmed, charmed-2018

The original *Charmed* series started in 1998, featured three white sisters with a Wiccan background and had the powers of Telekinesis, Time Freezing, and Premonition, powers originating from their Wiccan ancestor, Malinda Warren, centuries before. The 2018 reboot features three Afro-Latino sisters who discover both their bonds, and powers, after their mother, and Elder Witch, dies. Their abilities *also* include Telekinesis, Time Freezing, and *initially* Premonitions, but more directly,  mind reading/empathy.

It hasn't been stated to be the case, to my knowledge, but is there any information which shows that both series are taking place in different universes parallel to each other, or that they are linked anyway beyond theme and premise?

The CW has a way of doing this with their Warner Brother shows (The current *Arrowverse* shows are shown to be linked to the current *Supergirl* series, and *have* links with both the 1990 *The Flash* universe **and** the previous *Smallville* series.)

Given that both *Charmed* series aired on the WB/CW networks, I thought this might be viable.

Comment: The title says the reboot is from 2019, but the tags say [charmed-2018].  Which is it?

Comment: I think the Smallville and earlier Flash links came recently and as a direct result of very similar connections in comics (e.g. Crisis on Infinite Earths).  By contrast, *Charmed* is more of a direct reboot.

Comment: It's a straight reboot. https://telltaletv.com/2018/08/showrunner-jennie-snyder-urman-discusses-charmed-reboot-backlash-video/ Not set in the same universe.

Comment: @jwodder Mistype in the title. My bad. Now quit being pedantic, jeez....

Comment: @ValorumNo no, dude, I knwo it's a "Straight reboot" and _not_ in the **same** universe. I meant if the Universes were _connected_ in much the same way they managed to connect _Smallville_ to the the Arrowverse via the Crisis event. **Adamant** has more of the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Originally the plan was to place the show into its own private universe with no connection to the original show.

> During The CW's executive session at the Television Critics Association winter press tour, network head Mark Pedowitz explained that the new Charmed prequel series will be its own separate show - likely meaning characters from the original will not appear in the reboot.
>
> *Charmed prequel will be its own separate show, according to Mark Pedowitz. #TCA17*
>
> — [Kevin Yeoman (@kevintheyeoman) January 8, 2017](https://twitter.com/kevintheyeoman/status/818143619420864512)

Pedowitz did cautiously opened up the possibility of original characters making a return in some form.

> “At this point, it’s a self-contained, self-sustaining show,” Pedowitz
> says of the reboot of The WB supernatural fan favorite. “In terms of
> whether the [original] characters or actresses will come into the
> series, we’ll see what happens as the series goes on. That’s to be
> determined.”
>
> So, it’s not a prequel, right?
>
> “At this time, there is the Power of Three element in there, but at
> this time it’s a stand-alone, separate show.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Charmed reboot: Original cast not involved, 'unique story,' CW says](https://ew.com/tv/2017/01/08/charmed-reboot/?xid=entertainment-weekly_socialflow_twitter)</sup></sub>

There haven't been any substantive connections with the original show as yet and given the [animosity of original cast-members](https://www.usmagazine.com/entertainment/news/alyssa-milano-says-charmed-reboot-is-disrespectful/), that seems unlikely to happen.